# Точка пересечения координат

Tags: python, list, numpy, геометрия

Оранжевая линия **c** пересекает линию **x,y** в некой точке. Каждое значение **x** равняется какому то значению **h**. Как можно найти пересечение синей и оранжевой линии (назовем это точку cross например) и какой **h** она соответсвует? Думаю если значение находится между двумя **h** то округляем в сторону куда ближе.

```
x = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
y = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5]
h = [1127,1231,1237,1139,1127,1110,1185,1221,1031]

c = [2.0, 2.1428, 2.2857, 3.4285, 3.5714, 5.7142, 5.8857, 8.0]

plt.plot(x,y)  
plt.plot(c)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

UPD
Попробовал сделать по аналогии с комментарием ниже, но получается не то совсем:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
y = [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5]
h = [1127,1231,1237,1139,1127,1110,1185,1221,1031]

c = [2.0, 2.1428, 2.2857, 3.4285, 3.5714, 5.7142, 5.8857, 8.0,8]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
c = np.array(c)

plt.plot(x, y, '-')
plt.plot(c, '-')

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(x - c)).flatten())
plt.plot(x[idx], f[idx], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value

Comment: а зачем вы точки в списке `x` задали в обратном порядке?

Comment: вы же понимаете, что это все несколько усложняет? В первую очередь, для вас)

Comment: @matAAS, изменяя детали вопроса, __на который вам уже дали ответ__, вы можете инвалидировать данные ответы - не надо так делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# вы задали точки `x` в обратном порядке - исправляем этот "беспорядок"
x0 = np.sort(x)
# тоже самое делаем для `y`
y0 = np.array(y)[np.argsort(x)]
```

Сначала найдите коэффициенты линейной функции `f(x)`, которые будут лучше всего соответствовать точкам `x0` и `y0`:

```
coefficients = np.polyfit(x0, y0, 1)
f = np.poly1d(coefficients)
```

теперь у нас есть не просто набор точек лежащих на синей прямой, а сама функция задающая значения точек этой прямой.

Теперь можно [найти точку пересечения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28766902/5741205):

```
x1 = np.arange(len(c))
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(f(x1) - c))).flatten()
if idx:
    p_cross = np.array([x0[idx[0]], c[idx[0]]])
    print(f"Координаты точки пересечения: {p_cross}")
```

Вывод на экран:

```
Координаты точки пересечения: [4.     3.4285]
```

Comment: @matAAS, для этого вы можете задать новый вопрос. Изменять вопрос, таким образом, что после этого ответы становятся неправильными, не есть "гут")